# How to return char * aarr= new char[200] from C++ to Java using JNA

Tags: java, visual-c++, jna

I am new to JNA. in my one application I need to return   **char * aarr= new char[200]** to java from c. I cant understand how to do this. What should be the return type of my c++ function? And  how should I declare my java method to revive the char array ? 
Is there any other way like passing variable by reference in c++ to get the char[] value of c++?

Comment: Make sure that your return value is truly a NUL terminated C string, and that it's ASCII encoded.  If the string is UTF8 or other encoding, you'll need to indicate the encoding (extract `byte[]` from the pointer value and `Native.toString(byte[] data, String encoding)`.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani its way different from the link you just paste this is about JNA and  yours is about JNI

Comment: Assuming that the returned pointer truly points at a buffer of 260 chars (and not LPTCHAR or some such), extract the data with `Pointer.getByteArray(0, 260)` and print the results in hex.  That will show you the actual contents of memory, and if it contains human-readable content, you will see hex values in the ASCII range (0x40-0x7F or so).

JNA will only be able to extract the "correct" data when you know the size and format of the underlying data is (which apparently you don't, since `Pointer.getString(0)` doesn't produce the expected result).

Comment: @technomage i had edited my question please read tell me how would i map this things in java?

Comment: Please read my comment above.

Comment: If you pass in `byte[]` as a parameter in JNA, the C++ code can write to the resulting buffer and the caller will see the result.  If the native code truly returns a properly NUL terminated C string, then you can use String as a return type.  If none of this works, then the format of your string is not a nul-terminated C string, and you need to examine the contents of memory as described above to determine what format you *are* dealing with.

Comment: @technomage well let me clear that char * aarr= new char[3318000]. which gets data for an gray scale image.Now i want to somehow return this aarr in java get that image in java in order to further process the image as i am developing an xray image processing application
So now please guide me what to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you are returning a buffer from native code, you need to use `Pointer` and use the various pointer data access method to get/set data (`Pointer.getByteArray()` and `Pointer.setByteArray()`, for instance).  Note that if the data is allocated by native code, you must provide some way of disposing of the memory, so you'll need to either retain the pointer in native code for later disposal, or pass it back from Java (as a `Pointer`) so that your C++ can do the appropriate `delete[]` operation.

If you can allocate the buffer from the Java side (recommended if the Java side needs to manipulate the data extensively), use a direct `ByteBuffer` or `Memory` if the data is long-lived, or a primitive byte array if the native code only needs to access it for the duration of the native call.

The JNA documentation clearly indicates that native `char` maps to Java `byte`.

Also bear in mind that Java only has signed values, so you will need to convert the Java `byte` values (which may be negative) into a larger type (`short` or `int`) and mask out the upper bits, e.g.

`int data = (int)byteValue & 0xFF;`

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `Pointer.getCharArray(long offset,int arraySize)` [method of the pointer class](http://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Pointer.html#getCharArray%28long,%20int%29).

I guess what you are printing is arbitrary memory location of a pointer converted to string via default encoding.

Comment: getCharArray() is definitely the *wrong* thing to do for any `char` data.