# Returning `const char*` from native code and getting `String` in java

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, jna

I'm using JNA to interface my C++ code with java. I have a native function which takes a string as input and returns a string as output. 
Following is the C++ implementation of the function.

```
const char* decrypt(char* value){
    std::string res = TripleDes::getInstance().decrypt(value);
    std::cout<<res.c_str()<<"\n";
    return res.c_str();
}
```

I'm loading this function in a simple java program using JNA and trying to get a string from java. The problem is, I'm getting an empty string from java. Following is the java code:

```
interface NativeExample extends Library {
    NativeExample ne = (NativeExample) Native.loadLibrary("foo", NativeExample.class);
    String decrypt(String value);
}

public class Main{

        public static void main(String[] args){

                String decrypted =  NativeExample.ne.decrypt("foo");
                System.out.println(decrypted);

        }
}
```

The printed values from the C++ code are perfect but from Java, an empty string is printed. I've seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30414872/non-deterministic-return-values-string-type-from-calling-native-c-functions) but it gives a solution for JNI. I want to use JNA and return a string. How should I go about this?

I also tried to return JNA `Pointer` type and called `getString()` method on it. But prints gibberish which is not same across all invocations.

I do understand that I'm returning a dangling pointer in function scope which would get destroyed by the time it reaches java invocation. I want a simple solution to which I can return a String from C++ code to Java using JNA.

It is mentioned in the JNA documentation [here](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/overview-summary.html) that you should use `String` in java for the corresponding `const char*` in C/C++.

Comment: You're returning a dangling pointer in your C++ code.  The behavior when reading from it is undefined.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that from the question mentioned above. I want a solution.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm saying something stupid (I never really interfaced these two languages) but is it possible to return a dynamically allocated copy (with strcpy for instance [edit: strdup is better]) then expect the Java side to call back some "release(const char*)" C++ function which would free the allocated memory to avoid memory leaks ?

Comment: Perhaps JNA's copying happens too late? Could you return `strdup(res.c_str())` instead, and use `Pointer` as the type on the Java side?

Comment: @Caninonos I believe there's a good description of what you're trying to say in the documentation link mentioned in the question. I couldn't get it. Maybe you could.

Comment: @Michael it worked. Post it as an answer so that I can accept it. And also explain what you did.

Comment: @Michael that's a terrible solution!  You're copying a dangling pointer still.  It's a bit like saying that lying in the middle of a 20mph zone is safer than a motorway... either could cause problems!

Comment: @SaqibAhmed both.  Let me throw up an answer which should get you in the right direction

Comment: @UKMonkey: Admittedly it's been a while since my last coffee, but how am I using a dangling pointer if I returned a pointer to a newly allocated copy? One whose lifetime is not bound to the scope of `decrypt`.

Comment: @UKMonkey Michael isn't copying a dangling pointer (well as long as strdup happens inside C++'s decrypt). That said, Michael doesn't mention the possible issue of memory leaks if nothing is done to release the memory on the Java side.

Comment: ahh yes - I didn't see the strdup ... I too have suffered coffee shortages :(  Well, as @Caninonos says, it's still likely a memory leak.  Why not just return a std::string and then call 'String x(decrypted.c_str())'

Comment: @UKMonkey I tried to return `std::string` and it was throwing `std::bad_alloc` exception that's why I couldn't go in that direction.

Comment: I think the best solution is the "two-step" solution I mentioned earlier (and which indeed seems to be suggested by the documentation you gave a link to). Basically, Michael's suggestion is the first step. The second step is to have Java do something to avoid memory leaks. I don't know if you're familiar with C++'s dynamic allocation, but basically, once Java doesn't use your string anymore, you have to get the C++'s side to free the pointer you gave Java (basically, store the result of the C++ call as a "Pointer" ptr and when you're done, call C++'s free(ptr) from the Java side).

Comment: @Caninonos I am familiar with that. Kindly post it as an answer for future reference.

Comment: You could have the decrypt function accept an output buffer pointer and buffer size to which it writes the decrypted string, instead of returning the pointer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Caninonos' answer explains the problem sufficiently. Here's two different solutions.

### A) Dynamically allocate a string and provide a function for freeing it

You're going to have to free the string somehow, so do it properly. Provide a function which takes the pointer returned and frees it. Consider using [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) with [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statements.

C++

```
char* decrypt(char* value) {
    std::string res = TripleDes::getInstance().decrypt(value);
    std::cout << res.c_str() << "\n";
    return strndup(res.c_str(), res.size());
}

void free_decrypted_string(char* str) {
    free(str);
}
```

Java

```
interface NativeExample extends Library {
    NativeExample ne = (NativeExample) Native.loadLibrary("foo", NativeExample.class);

    Pointer decrypt(String value);
    void free_decrypted_string(Pointer str);
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pointer decrypted = NativeExample.ne.decrypt("foo");
        System.out.println(decrypted.getString(0));
        NativeExample.ne.free_decrypted_string(decrypted);
    }
}
```

In case you choose to utilize `AutoClosable`, you could benefit from a custom [`PointerType`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.5.1/javadoc/) which JNA allows you to use as an almost drop-in replacement for `Pointer`. However, since you're only really just getting the result, it might be better to encapsulate the JNA interface in a Java "decryptor" class which deals with the freeing. An `AutoClosable` would be better suited for things like file or process handles.

```
interface NativeExample extends Library {
    NativeExample ne = (NativeExample) Native.loadLibrary("foo", NativeExample.class);

    FreeableString decrypt(String value);
    void free_decrypted_string(FreeableString str);

    class FreeableString extends PointerType implements AutoCloseable {
        @Override
        public void close() {
            ne.free_decrypted_string(this);
        }
        public String getString() {
            return this.getPointer().getString(0);
        }
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (NativeExample.FreeableString decrypted = NativeExample.ne.decrypt("foo")) {
            System.out.println(decrypted.getString());
        }
    }
}
```

### B) Change the `decrypt` function to accept an output buffer

Instead of having to remember to release the dynamically allocated string, you could use output parameters. Ideally you'd want to use `size_t` instead of `int`, but using it is a bit awkward from JNA. If you need to work with strings longer than int max, figure out `size_t`.

Since you're using Triple DES, it may apply padding so the size of your output may differ from the input's length. To get around this, the function outputs the required size if the buffer was too small.

Notice that the function writes **no null terminator**, so make sure you use the returned value.

C++

```
int decrypt(const char *value, char *output, int *output_size) {
    std::string res = TripleDes::getInstance().decrypt(value);
    std::cout << res.c_str() << "\n";

    if (*output_size < res.size()) {
        *output_size = res.size();
        return 0;
    }

    size_t bytes_written = res.copy(output, *output_size);
    return (int)bytes_written;
}
```

Java

```
interface NativeExample extends Library {
    NativeExample ne = (NativeExample) Native.loadLibrary("foo", NativeExample.class);
    int decrypt(String value, byte[] output, IntByReference outputBufferSize);
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        IntByReference bufferSize = new IntByReference(buffer.length);

        int bytesWritten = NativeExample.ne.decrypt("foo", buffer, bufferSize);
        if (bytesWritten == 0 && bufferSize.getValue() > buffer.length) {
            // buffer was too small for decrypted output
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize.getValue()];
            bytesWritten = NativeExample.ne.decrypt("foo", buffer, bufferSize);
        }

        String decrypted = new String(buffer, 0, bytesWritten);
        System.out.println(decrypted);
    }
}
```

If you always know the size of your output, you can simplify the call to ignore the updated required buffer size, or drop it from the C++ function completely.

Comment: Seems like you can't pass a `const char*` to `free()`. Getting this exception: `invalid conversion from ‘const void*’ to ‘void*’ in free(str);`
I'm compiling with g++ on ubuntu where `free()` resides in `stdlib.h:483` with signature: `extern void free (void *__ptr) __THROW;`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem stems from a dangling pointer. In other words, once the C++ function `decrypt` returns the pointer to your character string, that string is released before Java has a chance to access it, causing undefined behaviour when accessed from the Java side.

The most straightforward way to solve the problem is then to extend the lifetime of that character string. For instance, by creating a dynamically allocated copy with `strdup`.

That said, while merely replacing `return res.c_str();` by `return strdup(res.c_str());` seemingly works, it suffers from another problem: it leaks memory. Indeed, dynamically allocated memory must explicitly and manually be freed in C++ but if nothing is done on the Java side, that string will sit in memory until your program terminates. Therefore, once the Java side is done with this string, it needs to notify the C++ side that it's no longer needed and can be safely released (with `free` in the case of `strdup` as mentioned in [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup), the same logic would apply to `new` and `delete`).

In order to do that, you'll need to store the C++'s call result in a Java `Pointer` object which will correctly store the C++'s `char*` necessary for the subsequent call to `free` (from the Java side to the C++ side).

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution to this problem is to use a callback function:

C++:

```cpp
typedef void (*callback_t) (const char*);

extern "C" {

void decrypt(char* value, callback_t output_func){
    std::string res = TripleDes::getInstance().decrypt(value);
    std::cout<<res.c_str()<<"\n";
    output_func(res.c_str());
}

}
```

Java:

```java
private interface MyCallback extends Callback {
    public void callback(String val);
}

interface NativeExample extends Library {
    NativeExample ne = (NativeExample) Native.loadLibrary("foo", NativeExample.class);
    String decrypt(String value);
}

public class Main{

        public static void main(String[] args){
                StringBuilder decryptedBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String decrypted =  NativeExample.ne.decrypt("foo", decryptedBuilder::append);
                System.out.println(decryptedBuilder.toString());

        }
}
```

It's perhaps not the most elegant solution, but a key advantage is that you don't have to deal with memory deallocation once you're done with the data.

For even more fun it's also possible to wrap the callback function in a `std::ostream`. This is particularly useful for when the C++ code already utilises the `<<` operator:

C++:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

typedef void (*callback_t) (const char*);

class callback_buffer : public std::stringbuf
{
    private:
        callback_t* func;
    public:
        callback_buffer(callback_t* func): func(func){}

        ~callback_buffer()
        {
            sync();
        }

        int sync()
        {
            (*func)(str().c_str());
            str("");
            return 0;
        }
};

extern "C" {

void decrypt(char* value, callback_t output_func){
    std::string res = TripleDes::getInstance().decrypt(value);
    std::cout<<res.c_str()<<"\n";
    callback_buffer buf(&func);
    std::ostream stream(&buf);
    stream << res;
}

}
```